# Trigger for multiplying two columns in oracle2

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
create or replace trigger BAND_T BEFORE insert or update OF average_song_time, number_of_songs on BAND
for each row
declare
   average_song_time number;
    number_of_songs number;
begin
    if (:new.average_song_time * :new.number_of_songs > 100)  ;
        then 
        raise_application_error(error -2010'Play Time is too high');
    end if;
end;

/
```

Wanting to multiply two columns together in Oracle2 and when the value of the two columns reaches over a certain amount my trigger will be fired, just wondering where im going wrong with this code?

Comment: The `declare` section isn't used. and `raise_application_error(error -2010'Play Time is too high');`
` should be `raise_application_error(-20010, 'Play Time is too high');`

Comment: create or replace trigger BAND_T
BEFORE
insert or update OF average_song_time, number_of_songs on BAND
for each row

begin
if
:new.average_song_time * :new.number_of_songs > 100  ;

then 
raise_application_error(-20010, 'Play Time is too high');end if;
end;
/

Comment: For future reference, `select * from user_errors` will show you your compilation errors.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Oracle 2". The current version is 12.2

Answer (score 0):

You did several errors (semi-colon where it doesn't fit, ERROR in RAISE statement, DECLARE section which is useless here).

See whether such an improved code does what you need.

```
create or replace trigger band_t
  before insert or update of average_song_time, number_of_songs
  on band
  for each row
begin
  if :new.average_song_time * :new.number_of_songs > 100 then
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'Play time is too high');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: ahh man you're a lifesaver its worked for me now much appreciated